# VS code Package.xml not retrieving new components

Tags: deployment, vs-code, package.xml

I am trying to retrieve new components such as ApexClass through "sfdx retrieve source in manifest from org" on the package.xml (sample below), and it doesn't retrieve any new components only updates whatever I currently have in my VS Code.

When I include the Apex Class name individually, only than will it retrieves it, what am I missing?

```
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>ApexClass</name>
</types>
<version>48.0</version>
```

Comment: Where is this `package.xml` located? Is it inside the `manifest` folder? Can you also try `sfdx force:source:retrieve -x path/to/package.xml` and share the result?

Comment: yes it is in manifest\package.xml, and ran it result retrieve, these apex classes "AccountController", "ContactController", but I also retrieve "BoatDataService" earlier by calling it directly in the package, but now with the wildcard * it doesn't seem to retrieve anymore.